# drag a scaled html canvas

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a canvas application, and implemented a zoom-in and out function using scale() and translate().
After zooming in, my canvas is actually bigger than it's seen on the screen, so I want to implement a drag and drop function for the whole canvas.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop what exactly?

You mean drag the whole canvas scene around? That's known as mouse-panning.

On the mousedown event, begin panning and save the mouse position

On the mousemove event, translate the context (`ctx.translate(x,y)`) by the difference between the current mouse position and the original position, then redraw the scene.

On the mouseup event, stop panning.

(There are harder ways, for instance you could implement scrollbars inside or outside the canvas)

Comment: I can't redraw the whole scene every mouse move - it takes a lot of time.

Comment: You should be able to do it, but you might have to start using optimizations. For instance you will only want to redraw the objects that the user can currently see with the canvas and skip the drawing of anything off-screen.